# How to hide the menu bar in Geany

Tags: lubuntu, openbox, menu-bar, geany

While configuring a Lubuntu 14.04.5 live version, I need to open a lightweight editor in a robust way, to do so I need to get ride of the menu bar, so the file to be edited can only be saved by pressing a hotkey. In the preferences, the other bars can get hidden, but not this one. I've also explored `openbox`, with no results.

Comment: Can't help with your actual problem but a somewhat related question was asked way back in 2011: http://lists.geany.org/pipermail/users/2011-October/007443.html and following posts. I'll just point out that openbox won't be expected to control whether or not the menu bar is visible. Openbox, in this context, is limited to the window decoration and the menu which appears at the top left of a window on pressing alt+spacebar.

Comment: You're right, @DKBose. If not to hide it, may be a way to block the options would be possible...

Comment: Here are two different solutions: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/633#issuecomment-660599849 https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/633#issuecomment-1030634638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be at least two options: one is to recompile Geany's sources after including a line like `gtk_widget_hide(menu_bar);`, where `menu_bar` would be the widget for the menu bar (you'll have to find out, don't know the exact name) -contribution by Pedro Cirne-; and the other is to install `topmenu` in Lubuntu 16.04 like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install topmenu-gtk-common
```

and then follow these [instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/05/how-to-get-global-menu-in-xubuntu-1604.html).

This will take Geany's menu bar to the global menu bar, which (in my case) is also hidden, so no more menu bars to play with.